# Including OpenSSL library in custom C++ library?

Tags: c++

I would like to write a security framework for mobile applications. The framework should not depend on a certain target platform (e.g. android). Therefore i want to use C++ and build my custom 'library' for the specific platforms (namely android in first step, maybe ubuntu touch later on). I want to use the framework for adding security relevant features in a modular fashion to any of my apps. For the very basic features, such as encryption, i want to use a accepted and common encryption library like openSSL.

In advance i read some articles about building C++ Libraries for Android (and wrapping them in JNI). For example i read the guide how to build openSSL for Android:
https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android

And this:
http://kvurd.com/blog/compiling-a-cpp-library-for-android-with-android-studio/

(both descriptions are linux specific, ... i'm using windows)

But i still have a very general question. I'm no c++ expert (i'm more familar with the java world indeed) and this is my first own 'library' ever. Is it possible to integrate or wrap an existing library like openSSL in my framework, so that i will have both 'packaged' together in one library which i can include in my mobile apps? (like using a .jar file in a java project and export this file together with the new code) Or will i have to build the framework and openSSL as seperate libraries for e.g. android? How could i reference from my framework to openSSL in this case?

Or is there even an easier way to provide such a framework in an 'cross-platform' way? I would totally prefer to write everything in java code and use a java library but i guess it would be difficult (or impossible) to use my framework for iOs or Ubuntu touch then...

I know even with the C++ way will be additional work necessary in android (writing the JNI wrapper). My aim is to re-use as much functionallity and code on the different platforms as possible. 
Any suggestion and hints are very welcome. Many thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I would like to use a dynamic lib, but i also accept answers for static solutions if that is more feasible.

Comment: What sort of library; static or dynamic?

Comment: Dynamic would be better. But in the end it doesn't matter. I will use whatever is easier to handle.

Comment: And what would be the steps to do that? For writing a Java Library I would just create a Java Library "Project", add the dependencies (such as other libs) and create my .jar File with everything together. What is the C++ way to do the same? (Note: I'm currently using Qt IDE for some testing, but I also used Visual Studio before.)

Comment: I would do it as an NDK library and openssl is probably already available as a standard library in Android.  You could then use JNI to integrate the NDK library with Java.  For other platforms, the apps would be written in C/C++ so easy to integrate.  However this is too complex for stackoverflow.

Comment: What is an NDK Library? And sadly openSSL is not available in android "out-of-the-box". afaik I would have to build it for android by myself. Maybe because JCA and SpongyCastle/BouncyCastle is sufficient (and i heard something about export limitations, but I'm not sure about that part). If i have to integrate both (my framework lib and openSSL) to android how could i do that?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Comment: I know what the NDK is. So -in your terms - a c++ library build with the NDK for android is an NDK Library? Ok, check for this point. But my main question is still open: How to get openSSL AND my Framework to android? My framework will have references to openSSL. I know how to build openSSL for android (roughly... if i would use a unix system). Maybe i would manage to get that to work. But how could i build my framework (with the openssl references) for android? I think that process would fail if i wouldn't build both together.

Comment: Build OpenSSL for Android (note: that means armv7 and x86 support) as a static library and link it in with your dynamic library at link time.